# How can I use inline footnote in markdown in blogdown?

Tags: markdown, hugo, blogdown

I found Yihui Xie used inline footnote in his [blog](https://yihui.org/en/2018/09/notebook-war/)([source](https://github.com/rbind/yihui/blob/master/content/en/2018-09-10-notebook-war.md)).

```
they use literate programming to explain TeX code.^[Is that because TeX code is particularly difficult to understand? I don't know. I don't understand TeX well.]
```

[image: footnote]

I created a site using [hugo-ivy theme](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-ivy) and used inline footnote in the [homepage](https://web.archive.org/web/20221110084421/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CyrusYip/blogdown-footnote/main/content/_index.md).

The content was:

```
---
title: Home
---

Here is an inline note^[Inline footnote does not work.].

Here is a footnote reference[^1].

[^1]: Reference footnote works.
```

But inline footnote does not work.

[image: my-footnote]

How can I use inline footnote in markdown file like Yihui?

You can visit [demo website](https://web.archive.org/web/20221110084010/https://footnote.netlify.app/).

Environment: Hugo 0.79.0, Blogdown 0.21.47

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm [still using Hugo 0.25.1](https://github.com/rbind/yihui/blob/e42b6877d2e00d48a06c1ab83863683a2cb96c75/netlify.toml#L5) at the moment. Its Markdown renderer is Blackfriday, which supports inline footnotes. [Hugo switched the default Markdown renderer to Goldmark](https://gohugo.io/content-management/formats/) since v0.60.0. Unfortunately, Goldmark doesn't support inline footnotes, and its author [doesn't seem to be interested](https://github.com/yuin/goldmark/issues/47) in supporting this feature, either.

[You could use](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration-markup/) Blackfriday as the Markdown renderer, but it will be deprecated eventually, so unless you are sure that you want to stick to a particular version of Hugo, this is probably not a good way to go. The alternative way is to use an editor that makes it easier to write footnotes, such as the [RStudio visual Markdown editor](https://rstudio.github.io/visual-markdown-editing) (then you won't need to think about footnote IDs).